# Why does the output of my shell script doesn't print in console?

Tags: java, shell, spring-boot, processbuilder

I am trying to print the output of a shell script on the console using java. When I manually run the script, I get

```
C:/Users/user1/Desktop/shell.sh: line 78: /usr/ucb/ps: No such file or directory
<STATUS>: Probe [ devicename ] is not running!
```

But, when I try to run it on my Java program, the output is not being printed on the console.
My code is:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe","C:/Users/user1/Desktop/shell.sh");

try {

    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    if (exitVal == 0) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        //abnormal...
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The only output I am getting is "Success". When I debugged my code, I found that the code never enters the condition

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

even though, in the bash terminal, there are lines of output. Why is this happening?

I am stuck at this point and I couldn't find any other explanations for this problem. Kindly help.

Comment: show the shell script

Comment: @dassum The shell file is basically 200 lines long and doesn't make any sense to me. But I tried by using a basic echo message also, it doesn't print output.

Comment: can you try with hello world shell script with echo message?

Comment: A bash script may print to stdout or to stderr. So maybe your script prints to stderr? That you could get from `process.getErrorStream()` instead of `process.getInputStream()`.

Comment: @dassum yes, I tried,but the echo message is not printing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are running git-bash.exe which opens as a windows application. Although Java has access to the stdout/stderr streams of git-bash.exe, these are not necessarily the same as the stdout/err of the internal launch of your shell script within git-bash.exe.

One way to see the stdout/err of your command would be to make a java friendly version of the .sh script which launches your original sh and redirects output to a specific files which you can then access within java afterwards.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/Git/GIT-BASH.EXE","/c/Users/blah/somescript.sh");
```

somescript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
runtheoriginalcommand > ~/somepath.out 2> ~/somepath.err
```

You could also add extra args to wrapper to pass the out/err files to be used so there is no contention with any other launches or hardcoded output files.